# T-SQL Remove "duplicate/non-interesting" data rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following set of data (sample given)

```
ID         Status  Code   Type       ModDate
1234       1       1      AB         1995-04-01
1234       1       1      CD         1998-08-31
1234       1       1      AB         2003-08-31
1234       1       NULL   AB         2008-11-08
1234       1       2      AB         2013-11-09
1234       1       1      EF         2013-11-18
...
```

As these data has to be viewed on some sort of timeline, I want to read just the following from the database, as only the `Type` changes are of interest:

```
ID         Status  Code   Type       ModDate
1234       1       1      AB         1995-04-01
1234       1       1      CD         1998-08-31
1234       1       1      AB         2003-08-31
1234       1       1      EF         2013-11-18
...
```

How can this be done? I tried to partition the data and give some row numbers, but it gives me headaches becuase the `Type` is grouped.

```
SELECT
    ID, Status, Code, Type, ModDate,
    MIN(ModDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type) MinModDate,
    MAX(ModDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type) MaxModDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type ORDER BY ModDate) RowNumber
FROM Data
```

Output:

```
ID         Status  Code   Type     ModDate       MinModDate    MaxModDate   RowNumber
1234       1       1      AB       1995-04-01    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   1
1234       1       1      CD       1998-08-31    1998-08-31    1998-08-31   1
1234       1       1      AB       2003-08-31    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   2
1234       1       NULL   AB       2008-11-08    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   3
1234       1       2      AB       2013-11-09    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   4
1234       1       1      EF       2013-11-18    2013-11-18    2013-11-18   1
...
```

Output expected:

```
ID         Status  Code   Type     ModDate       MinModDate    MaxModDate   RowNumber
1234       1       1      AB       1995-04-01    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   1
1234       1       1      CD       1998-08-31    1998-08-31    1998-08-31   1
1234       1       1      AB       2003-08-31    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   1
1234       1       NULL   AB       2008-11-08    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   2
1234       1       2      AB       2013-11-09    1995-04-01    2013-11-09   3
1234       1       1      EF       2013-11-18    2013-11-18    2013-11-18   1
...
```

Can this be achieved easily without using cursors?

Comment: why expected output second, third and fourth row gets not 1,2,3 row numbers, if you PARTITION BY ID and TYPE??

Comment: The partition works over all rows with `Type = AB` and applies the sorting afterwards. That's why the third row has `RowNumber = 2` and not 1 again, but this would be nice as I could just filter by `RowNumber = 1`

Comment: oh you want by same order to put Row number. Got it.

Comment: You using sql server 2012??

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2012 is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you use 2012 then this should work:

```
SELECT ID, Status, Code, Type, ModDate FROM 
(
SELECT
    ID, Status, Code, Type, ModDate,
    lag(type,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID, moddate) prevtype
FROM data
)t WHERE type<>ISNULL(prevtype,'')
```

Comment: Now the first row is missing `1234  1  1  AB  1995-04-01`. Is it because there is no previous row in this case?

Comment: I tested it on my machine and the first row is there. The isnull(prevtype,'') should protect when there is no previous row.

Comment: The inner select is correct, but I needed to modify the outer WHERE statement to `prevType IS NULL OR type <> prevType`. I'll accept your answer as most helpful to solve my issue.

Comment: You can use `WHERE ISNULL(Type,PrevType) IS NOT NULL` to avoid caring whether about whether `Type` is a string

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning the data is what you want, you just need to do it by Type, since that the only changes of interest.  You also need to add the ROW_NUMBER() function in order to filter the rows you want.  Here's an updated query.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  ID, [Status], Code, [Type], ModDate
            ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ModDate ORDER BY ModDate)
    FROM    #data
)
SELECT  ID, [Status], Code, [Type], ModDate
FROM    cte
WHERE   rn = 1
ORDER   BY ModDate, [Type]
```

Comment: With this statement, the row with data `1234  1  1  AB  2003-08-31` is missing

Comment: If Type is what you're interested in is Type by Mod, why should that AB row be included?  It's not clear based on the data.

Comment: I want to show changes in the `Type` column on a timeline and it is of course possible to change the `Type` back to a value which it had already in past and also to save the record once again with the same value. And I try to ignore these "same values".

Comment: I see. What's the timeline filter then? What if you had two entries for the same Type on the same day?  Would you then have to look at the seconds of the ModDate and take the most recent?

Comment: For simplification I removed the time part of the mode date, but its a DATETIME typed column

Comment: Ok, then wouldn't simply partitioning by ModDate in the CTE and then ordering by ModDate and Type give you what you need?  I updated the original logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just need to wrap your original SQL:

```
SELECT ID, Status, Code, Type, ModDate FROM 
(
SELECT
    ID, Status, Code, Type, ModDate,
    MIN(ModDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type) MinModDate,
    MAX(ModDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type) MaxModDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type ORDER BY ModDate) RowNumber
FROM Data
) t
WHERE ModDate=MinModDate
```

Comment: With this statement, the row with data `1234  1  1  AB  2003-08-31` is missing